# VBA Delete inserted signature in email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, signature

I use this code to display email drafts with pasted sheet content in the body. The body includes a signature at the bottom which is not a desired outcome. Signature is a default sig set up by user in Outlook app. How to remove it or not include in the first place when using such macro?

```
    Sub create_drafts()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Template As String
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object

    Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prep").Range("I1")
    Select Case Template
    Case "temp1"
        Set xlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template1")
        xlSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Case "temp2"
        Set xlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template2")
        xlSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Case "temp3"
        Set xlSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template3")
        xlSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    End Select


    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sharedmailbox@domain.com"
        .BodyFormat = 3
        .To = ""
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prep").Range("G1")
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the signature coming from? Please contact your systemadministrator about this, he/she can solve/answer this.

Comment: Untested, but try adding `.Body = ""` before doing the paste. Or use the helper function in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706852/delete-automatic-signature-from-forwarded-emails-vba-macro).

Comment: @Luuk Signature is a default sig set up by user in Outlook app. It has to be there for each and any message created manually. It's not supposed to be in the message when using macro.

Comment: With code given [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4716-excel-vba-send-email-with-signature.html) is see than my Signature is not added (by default). I did test this with Office2013 (Excel, using Outlook to send mail)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to remove the `.Display` method call the signature may not be added.

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sharedmailbox@domain.com"
        .BodyFormat = 3
        .To = ""
        .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prep").Range("G1")
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
    End With
```

Use the `Send` method instantly to prevent the signature from adding.

But if you still need to display the result message item to a user, you can find signatures stored on the local hard drive in the following places:

- Windows XP

`C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures`

- Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`

So, you could read the signature content and delete a corresponding part from the message body.